# Plus/Minus animated comment icon

Tags: comments, icon, animated, gif

[image: the animated plus/minus icon]

So I've seen this animated gif icon on many, many websites.
It seems to always be related to comments or feedback. My questions are:

1. What is the common name for it?

2. Who created it?

I would like to use this image on my own website, but I need to figure out if I can get permission to do so.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: Editing the question to include something like "I would like to use this image on my own website, but I need to figure out if I can get permission to do so" would satisfy the on-topic requirements for this site.

Comment: I love that the attention on this question is its format, not its answer. Thanks for the help though @StephenOstermiller.

Comment: Your best bet would be to attempt to replicate it with your own design.

Answer (score 1):

To answer #2 - I believe it was originally created by [OpionLab](https://www.opinionlab.com/), which is an enterprise-class feedback management service.  You'd have to subscribe to their service to get permission to use it.

Comment: Hi Dale. You guys must be really, really busy tracking down all the poor slobs using that comment icon and demanding royalties.